# center Jquery Easy Ui layout title

Tags: html, jquery-easyui

I am using an Easy UI layout and have a title like that
`<div data-options="region:'north'" style="height:20px" align="center" title="Decision Support System for Accidental Pollution" ></div>`. 
The problem is that the text "Decision support system..." is not centered and I can not change fonts/colors/size. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just add some html code in title properties like :

```
<div data-options="region:'north'" style="height:20px" align="center"  title="<center>Decision Support System for Accidental Pollution</center>" > </div>
```

or for center and bold :

```
<div data-options="region:'north'" style="height:20px" align="center"  title="<center><b>Decision Support System for Accidental Pollution</b></center>" > </div>
```